# How to show full tree from particular parent in javascript with c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

we are trying to show HierarchyTrees from database without any condition it show's fine.

but when we apply condition for particular user, then showing only root's three child but not showing child's sub child.

i have created one InputBox, by using InputBox i passed the Parent Id with condition, but it showing only three childs not showing full tree .

**This is Front end code**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

     <div id="chart">
</div>
    <input type="text" id="txtSearch" runat="server" value="t" clientidmode="Static" />

</asp:Content>
```

****This is Javascript code****

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["orgchart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm21.aspx/GetChartData",

            data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Entity');
                data.addColumn('string', 'ParentEntity');
                data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
                for (var i = 0; i < r.d.length; i++) {
                    var memberId = r.d[i][0].toString();
                    var memberName = r.d[i][1];
                    var sp = r.d[i][3];
                    var parentId = r.d[i][2].toString() ? r.d[i][2].toString() : '';
                    data.addRows([[{
                        v: sp,
                        f: memberName + '<div><img src = "Pictures/' + memberId + '.jpg" /></div>'
                    }, parentId, memberName]]);
                }
                var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart($("#chart")[0]);
                chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

****This is Backend code****

```
[WebMethod]
        public static List<object> GetChartData(string username)
        {

            string query = "SELECT RegionLoginOID, RegionName, SponserID,Child_Id";
            query += " FROM RegionLogin where SponserID LIKE ''+@SponserID+'%' ";
            
            using (SqlConnection con = ClsConnection.Connections())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SponserID", username);
                    List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            chartData.Add(new object[]
                    {
                        sdr["RegionLoginOID"], sdr["RegionName"], sdr["SponserID"], sdr["Child_Id"]
                    });
                        }
                    }
                    
                    return chartData;
                }
            }
        }
```